# MATLAB: Breaking matrix into multiple lines

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop

If I have a matrix as such:

```
a= [90,23,0,91,24,0,92,35,0]
```

And I would like to break the matrix as shown below:

```
a= [90,23,0;
91,24,0;
92,35,0]
```

Is there any way of doing that? I have very long matrices which need to broken up as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `reshape()` may help

```
a = reshape(a,[],3)'
```

If matrix is complex, it is better to use the operation `.'`

```
a = reshape(a,[],3).'
```

in order to avoid complex conjugation

Comment: Beware of that `'`; `a` might be complex!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reshape(a,[3,3])` to turn your array into a 3x3 matrix, and then for your specific order you can transpose it: `reshape(a,[3,3])'`